# I need a switch with 8 ports and the ability to configure the ports as Hybrid and setup VLANs

Tags: networking, switch

First and foremost - this is not for a normal network. This is in a product/lab environment that happens to use ethernet.

I currently have a HP 1910 switch that I configured exactly like I want, and it works. However, I cannot keep using this specific piece of hardware and need something 1) new (because 1910s aren't sold anymore) and 2) I need a smaller number of ports, so this switch can fit in an enclosed space/be easier to move around/travel with.

I am having trouble looking through Cisco and Aruba switches as the manuals I have found don't seem to be able to configure ports to Hybrid.

As a side question, is "Hybrid Port Link Type" functionality only in L2 or L3 switches? Or is there another way to tell that a switch supports it?